# How to lock the thread until the Observable be complete

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, observable, spring-cloud-stream

I'm testing a scenario, where i want to send an event, and watching when the consumer finishes processing to continue the flow, ie when i trigger the event, i need that main thread to be blocked until the end of the consumer processing , using rxJava Observable, i did not succeed to lock the main thread to wait for the observable result.

My producer

```
@Service
public class Producer {

    private MessageChannel output;

    @Autowired
    private Consumer consumer;

    @Autowired
    public Producer(Processor processor) {
        this.output = processor.output();
    }

    public void send(String event) {

        System.out.println("SENDING EVENT...");

        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(event).build());

        //Observable<Boolean> obs = consumer.execute();
        //obs.subscribe();

        //Blocking process
        BlockingObservable.from(consumer.execute()).subscribe();

        //Continue to flow
        System.out.println("EVENT PROCESSED...");

    }
}
```

My Consumer

```
@Service
public class Consumer {

    @StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT)
    public void receiver(@Payload String event){

        System.out.println("EVENT RECEIVED, PROCESSING...");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        execute();

    }

    public Observable<Boolean> execute() {
        return Observable.<Boolean>create(emitter -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("EVENT STILL PROCESSING...");
                emitter.onNext(Boolean.TRUE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(new RuntimeException("ERROR"));
            }
            emitter.onCompleted();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `BlockingObservable.toFuture(consumer.execute()).get()` to block the thread instead of `BlockingObservable.from(consumer.execute()).subscribe()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the operators toBlockig(Wait to consumer to consume) + single to get the value.

```
   @Test
    public void observableEvolveAndReturnToStringValue() {
        assertTrue(Observable.just(10)
                             .map(String::valueOf)
                             .toBlocking()
                             .single()
                             .equals("10"));
    }
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/utils/ObservableToBlocking.java